# Infinite Continued Fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

$$A = a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{a_4 + \cdots}}},$$ where $a_n = f(n), f:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Is there an easy way of calculating the value of $A$ using algebra and/or simple calculus for a given $f(n)$?
And are all such fractions convergent?

Comment: All such regular continued fractions are convergent.  I doubt there's a simple way to compute the value for an arbitrary $f$, but I'm no expert.  There's a beautiful [book](https://www.amazon.com/Continued-Fractions-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486696308) by Khinchin on the subject.

Comment: The only real way of computing $A$ is available when the sequence $a_n$ is (eventually) periodic. Apart from that, very rarely does $A$ have any reasonable closed form. To showcase the complexity of what we are dealing with, for $a_n=n$ the value of $A$ requires Bessel functions to express, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstants.html)